# Not getting the console login prompt in HP ILO 3

Tags: hp, login, ilo, prompt

Not able to get the console login in the ILO 3. When I am entering the vsp command in the ilo it is not showing the console login prompt.

Tried to reset the ilo(from the Diagnostic Option in the Web GUI) but still the console login prompt is not coming.

Need help to get the console login prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your OS to use the serial port as a console. This will be OS-dependent.

Some possible help:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=redhat+hp+vsp
- https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+server+hp+vsp